# Hash an std::array which used in std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map

I have an very strange problem about use self-defined hash function in std::unordered_map.

My key type is bigger than int64, so I use std::array to represent it.
To get it hash value, I create a MyHash class:

```
class MyHash
{
public:
    std::size_t operator()(const std::array<char, 12>& oid) const
    {
        Convert t;
        std::memcpy(t.arr, oid.data(), 12);
        std::cout << t.a <<" "<<t.b << std::endl;
        return (std::hash<std::int32_t>()(t.a) ^ (std::hash<std::int64_t>()(t.b) << 1)) >> 1;
    }
    union Convert {
        struct {
            std::int32_t a;
            std::int64_t b;
        };
        char arr[12];
    };
};
```

First, test it:

```
std::array<char, 12> arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
MyHash o;
o(arr);
o(arr);
```

It's OK. It print same `t.a` and `t.b`. Now use it with std::unordered_map:

```
std::unordered_map<std::array<char, 12>, int, MyHash> map;
std::array<char, 12> arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
map.insert(std::make_pair(arr, 1));
auto it = map.find(arr);
if(it == map.end())
    std::cout << "error";
else
    std::cout << it->second;
```

Now, it will print `error`, the reason is the `t.b` in insert is different with find. And this only happen in vs release mode (or g++ O2)

Comment: I'd rather calculate a hash of all 12 bytes using e.g. `boost::hash_range`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cddb1ea79a18d0b1

Comment: First I use it but I found it is a bit slow because it will do 12 times hash. And the quality is not good due to the first 4 bytes in array are almost same value

Comment: if the first 4 bytes are always the same, you could just skip them when calculating the hash (`boost::hash_range(oid.begin()+4, oid.end());`); did you measure the time difference? how much slower is it than your memcpy/union approach?

Comment: memcpy is 2 times faster. Actually, the array is bson objectId: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/ boost::hash_range hardly has a global view of the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid undefined behavior, packing and alignment issues, you may copy to individual integers:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <array>

std::size_t array_hash(const std::array<char, 12>& array) {
    std::uint64_t u64;
    std::memcpy(&u64, array.data(), 8);
    std::uint32_t u32;
    std::memcpy(&u32, array.data() + 8, 4);
    // return (std::hash<std::uint32_t>()(u32) ^ (std::hash<std::uint64_t>()(u64) << 1)) >> 1;;
    return u64 + u32; // for simplicity
}

std::size_t uint_hash(std::uint64_t u64, std::uint32_t u32) {
    // return (std::hash<std::uint32_t>()(u32) ^ (std::hash<std::uint64_t>()(u64) << 1)) >> 1;;
    return u64 + u32; // for simplicity
}
```

With (g++ version 4.8.4)  g++ -S --std=c++11 -O3 you will get:

```
_Z10array_hashRKSt5arrayIcLm24EE:
.LFB914:
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    8(%rdi), %eax
        addq    (%rdi), %rax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

and

```
_Z9uint_hashmj:
.LFB915:
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    %esi, %eax
        addq    %rdi, %rax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

... which is fairly optimal.

See also: [Type Punning, Strict Aliasing, and Optimization](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/959)

Comment: +1 for making an effort to avoid UB and linking to a warning about how volatile all this is. I'm glad that I've gotten to a point where seeing `reinterpret_cast` makes me flinch and I know to use `memcpy` if there's _any_ uncertainty. Plus, as you've shown, often the compiler will optimise the `memcpy` into what you'd expect from a `reinterpret_cast`... but with the guaranteed defined behaviour of the former, unlike the latter. The best of both worlds!

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this

```
  union Convert {
        struct {
            std::int32_t a;
            std::int64_t b;
        };
        char arr[12];
    };
```

The compiler may well *pack* extra bytes between `a` and `b`. So the type punning through the `char` array will not necessarily overlay the `struct` part. Type punning is also borderline undefined behaviour in C++; although I *think* you're OK in this particular instance.

It appears that the packing arrangements for the release build differ from the debug build.

Many compilers allow you to specify the packing arrangements (`#pragma pack`?) but I wouldn't rely on that if I were you since it defeats the compiler's optimisation strategies and is also essentially non-standard C++.

Comment: Swapping the order of `a` and `b` will remove the padding between because the 64bit int has to be 8 byte aligned while the 32bit int only has to be 4 byte aligned.

Comment: It might not do that. Especially on a 128 bit chip.

Comment: The memory layout padding should not be decide at compile time? The char array may not overlay a and b completely, but why it will change in runtime? And it only happen when use it as unordered_map hash object?

Comment: @Bathsheba Sure the compiler may insert padding at will, but it only inserts padding to comply with alignment requirements. Provided that the hypothetical 128 bit chip can load a (q/d/h)word from a (q/d/h)word aligned address (I don't know of a chip that can't), then there is no reason for over alignment of fundamental types of size 2^x bytes. Thus the compiler will not add padding in the above example, even on a 128 bit chip. Providing it is not a silly chip that can only perform 128 bit aligned loads, or some other pathological case.

Comment: Re type punning - There's no "borderline" about it. UB is UB. `union`s cannot be used to for 'punning', with the sole exception of if the members are `struct`s sharing a _common initial_ sequence of members.

Comment: @underscore_d: that's the one. Thank you!

Comment: @Bathsheba You're welcome! I'd recommend editing that in. ;-) And to clarify my comment, it's only defined if the `union` members are standard-layout and we're reading/writing their members within the CIS... not for punning entire `struct`s or anything weird like that. It's a great allowance, though! Neatly covers my 'low level' needs and avoids me having to use any implementation-defined hackery. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack but you could try it and see how it works:

```
struct MyHash {
    std::size_t operator()(const std::array<char, 12>& oid) const {
        auto d = reinterpret_cast<const std::uint32_t*>(oid.data());
        std::size_t prime = 31;
        std::size_t other_prime = 59;
        return d[2] + other_prime*(d[1] + prime*d[0]);
    }
};
```

This only works because 12 is a multiple of `sizeof(uint32_t)` mind you. If the size changes you'll have to adjust.